# Trying to set timer on a switch with jQuery

Tags: jquery, timer, switch-statement

With the help of Google (and a lot of results here at StackOverflow) my co-worker and I have managed to scrap together a "rotator". The main picture with blue buttons on the right at www.buisnessinlake.com for reference.

We have it functioning properly but now we're trying to get it to automatically switch between the different states at set intervals. We're using a switch to do this now but would like to add the auto part. I've found other script examples on how to add a timer, but not one that works with a switch like this, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

This is where we're at:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var theid = $("div.open").attr("id");

    //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION   
    $('div.accordionButton').click(function () {
        // console.warn(theid);
        var theitem = $("#" + theid);
        var doanimation = true;
        if ($(this).attr("id") == theid) {
            doanimation = false;
        };

        theid = $(this).attr("id");

        if (doanimation) {
            switch (theid) {
                case "rotator_1":
                    $('div.arrow').animate({
                        left: '-24',
                        top: '-3'
                    }, 300, function () {
                        // Animation complete.
                    });
                    $('#picsunder').css("background-image", "url(../../content/images/rotator_1.png)");
                    $('#pics').fadeTo('slow', 0, function () {
                        //animationcomplete
                        $(this).css("background-image", "url(../../content/images/rotator_1.png)");
                        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
                    });
                    break;

                case "rotator_2":
                    $('div.arrow').animate({
                        left: '-24',
                        top: '55'
                    }, 300, function () {
                        // Animation complete.
                    });
                    $('#picsunder').css("background-image", "url(../content/images/rotator_2.png)");
                    $('#pics').fadeTo('slow', 0, function () {
                        //animationcomplete
                        $(this).css("background-image", "url(../content/images/rotator_2.png)");
                        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
                    });
                    break;

                case "rotator_3":                      
                    $('div.arrow').animate({
                        left: '-24',
                        top: '113'
                    }, 300, function () {
                        // Animation complete.
                    });
                    $('#picsunder').css("background-image", "url(../content/images/rotator_4.png)");
                    $('#pics').fadeTo('slow', 0, function () {
                        //animationcomplete
                        $(this).css("background-image", "url(../content/images/rotator_4.png)");
                        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
                    });
                    break;

                case "rotator_4":
                    $('div.arrow').animate({
                        left: '-24',
                        top: '171'
                    }, 300, function () {
                        // Animation complete.
                    });
                    $('#picsunder').css("background-image", "url(../content/images/rotator_3.png)");
                    $('#pics').fadeTo('slow', 0, function () {
                        //animationcomplete
                        $(this).css("background-image", "url(../content/images/rotator_3.png)");
                        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
                    });
                    break;

            }
        }
        //console.warn(theid);
        $("div.accordionButtonSelected").removeClass("accordionButtonSelected").addClass("accordionButton");
        $("div.accordionContentSelected").removeClass("accordionContentSelected").addClass("accordionContent");
        $(this).next().removeClass("accordionContent").addClass("accordionContentSelected");
        $(this).removeClass("accordionButton").addClass("accordionButtonSelected");
        $('div.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
    });

    //HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD    
    $("div.accordionContent").hide();

    //Opens DIV on load that has the ID of "open"
    $("div.open").trigger('click');

});
```

Here's the HTML as requested:

```
 <div id="photo_rotator">
 <div id="pics"></div>
 <div id="picsunder"></div>
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="accordionButton open" id="rotator_1">Why Lake</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">@Html.ActionLink("Our prime location and business-friendly approach make Lake County the perfect location to live, work and play.", "Index", "WhyLake", Nothing, New With {.class = "rotator"})</div>
    <div class="accordionButton shadow" id="rotator_2">Opportunity Centers</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">@Html.ActionLink("Lake County’s three Business Opportunity Centers offer a myriad of programs and services to support your business.", "BusinessOpportunityCenters", "BusinessSupport", Nothing, New With {.class = "rotator"})</div>
    <div class="accordionButton shadow" id="rotator_3">Economic Coordinators</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">@Html.ActionLink("Lake County’s economic development coordinators are here to assist with the information or support your business needs.", "EconomicDevelopmentCoordinators", "BusinessSupport",  Nothing, New With {.class = "rotator"})</div>
    <div class="accordionButton shadow" id="rotator_4">Site Selection</div>
    <div class="accordionContent"><a class="rotator" href="http://propertyfinder.lakecountyfl.gov">With an abundance of available land and vacant building space, we can pinpoint the perfect site to locate your business.</a></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how I can add a simple timer to switch between each case every 10 seconds? Most appreciated!

Comment: It would really help to see some HTML since the website appears to be down

Comment: Oh, terribly sorry. it's www.businessinlakefl.com. forgot the fl. I also added the HTML to the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take that big ol anonymous function defined here

```
$('div.accordionButton').click(function () {
```

And nomify it

```
function doRotateImage(event)
{
   //stuff you already have
}
```

then  you wire up your button to it

```
$('div.accordionButton').click(doRotateImage);
```

And now you make a function to rotate on a timer

```
function autoRotate()
{
   doRotateImage();
   setTimeout( autoRotate, 10 * 1000);  
}
```

Now call autoRotate() somewhere once to start it up.

You will have to tinker with it but this is the basic idea

Comment: Well, I didn't fully grasp what you were getting at with this, but it was enough for us to get it working. We went much farther and did much more than I figured would happen, but we got it. Thanks!